# Rotating two rectangles as a whole

Tags: math, rotation, geometry

I have two rectangles which are 100x100 pixels each. One is red, one is blue, like this:

[image: pic1]

I can rotate both rectangles by 45 degrees by applying a 2D rotation matrix to all vertices using the following steps:

1. Translate each vertex to the origin, i.e. translate each vertex
   by -50 on both axes.
2. Apply a rotation of 45 degrees.
3. Translate vertices back.

The result looks like this:

[image: pic2]

However, this isn't exactly what I want. What I'd like to have is this:

[image: pic3]

How would I have to calculate the rotated vertices of the rectangles to get a result as shown above?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you group them together in some way? Also, what language is this? SVG? CSS?

Comment: Java but I think it's a rather generic thing, not in any way related to any language which is why I left that out.

Comment: Well, it may then be off topic because it's more math than programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find desired vertices positions, rotate them about middle point (mx,my) of common edge. So for every vertex:

```
Translate its coordinates by -mx, -my  
Apply a rotation of 45 degrees  
Translate vertex  back by mx, my.
```